# realm: Couldn't join realm: Insufficient permissions to join the domain example.local

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos, sssd

> I was able to join all other centos linux instance but not this one even though I have AD admin access, still I am getting this error

- Resolving: _ldap._tcp.example.local
- Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: XXX.XX.XXX.X
- Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: XXX.XX.XXX.X
- Successfully discovered: example.local
  Password for user@example.LOCAL:
- Required files: /usr/sbin/oddjobd, /usr/libexec/oddjob/mkhomedir, /usr/sbin/sssd, /usr/bin/net
- LANG=C LOGNAME=root /usr/bin/net -s /var/cache/realmd/realmd-smb-conf.7J0AR1 -U user@example.LOCAL ads join example.local
  Enter user@example.LOCAL's password:ads_print_error: AD LDAP ERROR: 50 (Insufficient access): 00000005: SecErr: DSID-031A11B9, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0

Failed to join domain: Failed to set account flags for machine account (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)

! Insufficient permissions to join the domain example.local
realm: Couldn't join realm: Insufficient permissions to join the domain example.local

---

***sudo kinit -V  user@example.LOCAL |||
Successfully Authenticated to krb5***

---

***sudo realm join -U user@example.LOCAL example.LOCAL | Refer to the error mentioned above on the post***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `rdns=false` under the `[libdefaults]` section in the `/etc/krb5.conf` file fixed the issue for me.

Example:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = DOMAIN.COM
rdns = false
```

Answer (score 0):

is this in AWS? if so here is the real solution.

The isuse is amazon is doing rdns for you .. you need to disable that.

disable Autodefined rules for reverse DNS resolution in route53. That removes the compute.internal from being retuned. Its that rdns thats coming back thats causing the issue you are having.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver-automatic-forwarding-rules-reverse-dns.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).